# How to get value from each range from multitable on excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

i have some table on excel and i want to generate the content of table to my custom format.

[this is my list of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDEXF.png)

this is my code:

```
Dim field As String
Dim table As String
Dim t As Integer
Dim f As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim myFile As String
Dim xStr As String
Dim lastcode As String
Dim TableID As Integer
Dim i As Integer


myFile = "D:\table.txt"

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To .ListObjects.Count
    table = "{" & Chr(10) & _
    """type"":""Table""," & Chr(10) & _
    """details"": {" & Chr(10) & _
    """name"": """ & .Range("C2") & """," & Chr(10) & _
    """sort"": ""manual""," & Chr(10) & _
    """attributes"": ["
    Print #1, table

    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For f = 2 To lastrow
        field = "{" & Chr(10) & _
        """names"": [" & Chr(10) & """" & .Range("B" & f) & """" & Chr(10) & _
        "]," & Chr(10) & _
        """id"": " & f - 1 & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "}"

        If f = lastrow Then
            field = field
        Else
            field = field & ","
        End If

        Print #1, field
    Next f

        lastcode = "]," & Chr(10) & _
        """uniqueGroups"": []," & Chr(10) & _
        """id"": " & i & Chr(10) & _
        "}" & Chr(10) & _
        "}"

        Print #1, lastcode
    Next i
        Close #1
End With
```

My Expected i got format like this, but i cant get range for each value from each table on looping

```
{
      "type": "Table",
      "details": {
        "name": "customer",
        "sort": "manual",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "names": [
              "id"
            ],
            "id": 1
          },
          {
            "names": [
              "name"
            ],
            "id": 2
          }
        ],
        "uniqueGroups": [],
        "id": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Table",
      "details": {
        "name": "address",
        "sort": "manual",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "names": [
              "id"
            ],
            "id": 1
          },
          {
            "names": [
              "customer_id"
            ],
            "id": 2
          }
        ],
        "uniqueGroups": [],
        "id": 1
      }
    }
```

Comment: ListObjects have properties such as `DataBodyRange` which you can use to read out your rows without having to use something like `End(xlUp)`.  See (eg)  https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

Comment: Hi thanks, from that blog, i use this code to get the value, lastcode = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(i).DataBodyRange(3, 2).Select
MsgBox lastcode, but just get True on MsgBox, any advice to correct my code

Comment: Drop the `.Select`

Comment: i got the answer. change `.Select` to `.Value`